# Type of Differential Equation $y''''$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm doing some differential equations exercises where I found this equation:

$$ y'''' + 2y'' + y = \sin t $$

I wanted to know which type of equation is this one, I'm not asking for the solution just the type of equation so I can have an idea of what to do.

Thanks!

**EDIT** So, what I'm doing is that I find the homogenous solution, which is:

$$ F*\cos t + G*\sin t $$

Then I do the particular solution:

$$ A*t*\sin t + B*t*\cos t $$

I find the derivatives and then I replace in the original equation, but when I do this I get this:

$$ 0 = \sin t $$

Comment: Its a fourth order ODE with constant coefficients. Try the solution $y = e^{rt}$ and determine $r$. Then find the particular solution, similar to 2nd order ODEs which I assume you've probably done.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for equations and mathematical expressions.

Comment: It's Its a fourth order inhomogeneous **linear** ODE with constant coefficients.

Comment: Yeah! That's what I was doing but when I try to find the particular solution with Yp = A*t*sin(t) + B*t*cos(t), when I replace in the equation everything gives me 0 so I can't find A or B

Comment: In the solution, you should also have $C\sin(t)+D\cos(t)+E t^2 \sin(t)+F t^2 \cos(t)$ I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is NOT the general solution to the homogeneous equation! $y''''+ 2y''+ y= 0$ has characteristic equation $r^4+ 2r^2+ 1= (r^2+ 1)^2= 0$.

That is a fourth degree equation so has 4 roots. It can be reduced to $r^2+ 1= 0$.  $r= i$ and $-i$ are **double** roots.  The general solution is $y(t)= F \cos(t)+ G \sin(t)+ P t\cos(t)+ Q t\sin(t)$.

In order to get the specific solution that makes $y''''+ 2y'+ y= \sin(t)$, let $y(t)= At^2 \cos(t)+ Bt^2 \sin(t)$.